# Problems publishing working application to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 build that is building and running locally without any problems whatsoever. I cannot however publish to Azure. I'm publishing with Intellitrace enabled and I'm seeing that an exception is being thrown attempting to activate the role.

`Exception Thrown: "Requested registry access is not allowed." (System.Security.SecurityException)`

I have made sure of the following:

- I have the latest edition of the Microsoft Azure SDK
- All the relevant project references for all of my project references are set to Copy Local: True
- All the relevant libraries have the correct binding redirects in their respective app.config/web.config files
- All the Azure references in my project are to the correct versions of the assemblies

The event log shows the following exceptions in chronological order:

> Error   4/11/2014 3:23:57 AM    SRMSVC  8228    None
>
> File Server Resource:   Manager was unable to access the following
>   file or volume: 'E:'.  This   file or volume might be locked by
>   another application right now, or   you might need to give Local
>   System access to it.
>
> Error 4/11/2014 3:31:44 AM    .NET Runtime    1026    None
>
> Application:
>   DiagnosticsAgent.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsGuidNamedEventProvider.GetNamedEvent(System.String)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Common.BlockingExecutionEnvironment.Execute(System.Func`1)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.Program.Main(System.String[])
>
> Error 4/11/2014 3:31:44 AM    .NET Runtime    1026    None
>
> Application:
>   DiagnosticsAgent.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsGuidNamedEventProvider.GetNamedEvent(System.String)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Common.BlockingExecutionEnvironment.Execute(System.Func`1)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.Program.Main(System.String[])
>   .
>   Error 4/11/2014 3:31:45 AM    Application Error   1000    (100) Faulting
>   application name: DiagnosticsAgent.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x5243ef34 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.2.9200.16451, time stamp: 0x50988aa6 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000003811c Faulting process id: 0x9c Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cf55368ce74b73 Faulting application path:
>   E:\plugins\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe Faulting module path:
>   D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   cdd18167-c129-11e3-93f5-00155d85a04e Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:Server ResourceApplication:

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the following error:

"File Server Resource Manager was unable to access the following file or volume: 'E:'.  This file or volume might be locked by another application right now, or you might need to give Local System access to it."

We resolved the issue by updating our project references.  If you are getting this error, check your Azure references, specifically these two:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics

Ensure that your references are the appropriate Azure SDK version to the schema/SDK you are pointing to in Azure.